# Use case for mysql users depending on host

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What is the use case for having different passwords for the same username but different hosts on mariadb/mysql?

Is there a way to synchronized the password for the same username for different hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just make 'user'@'%', except that it doesn't match 'localhost', so still have to make that one explicitly.

Comment: intriguing. that does help.